# Does code in methods always get executed?

Tags: java

I have created the implementation of a abstract method of the super class. Does the code in the method always get executed or is there some kind of cache that knows the code will never change?

I want to know if there are performance issues with my code. Is it better to create the map as a member variable and then return it in the method?

```
@Override
protected Map<String, Function<Information, String>> getDefinitionMap() {
    final Map<String, Function<Information, String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("Name", t -> t.getName());
    map.put("ID", t -> t.getId());
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; if you want prevent subclasses from overwriting the code, you have to declare the function as `final`.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Only if your method is final then sometimes compiler can copy the byte code of that final method for subroutine directly inline with the compiled code of the calling method. And hence removes the headache of compiling the method code again and again.

Comment: Some remarks to the question: first, this is not an "abstract method" and second, even if the code does not change (btw. it never does), the computed result may change in general.

Comment: Sorry I meant it's the implementation of a abstract method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time the method `getDefinitionMap()` is called, a new `LinkedHashMap` instance is created. There is no "implicit caching".

You can avoid that, if you create the map once, store it in a member variable and return this. You may want to make it unmodifiable so that it cannot be changed by callers. (see `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap`)

Comment: In fact, this is the kind of thing I'd create a `public final static` for.

Comment: @daniu yes, this is an alternative if you don't have to override it in subclasses.